# Indirect objects before direct objects because they’re pronouns

Tags: indirect-objects

Is there a rule out there that says the indirect object is placed before the direct object if it is a pronoun? I read in on another post, and don’t understand it. Before you say to comment on that post, I did and was told to post another question.
Here’s the link
[Order of prepositions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65016/order-of-prepositions)
It is found in sanders’ answer

Answer (score 1):

In general, if the direct object is a pronoun, [a prepositional phrase is preferred](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm) to an indirect object.

This is acceptable use of `her` as the indirect object:

> He gave her the book.

This form is not commonly used:

> He gave her it.

It is better as:

> He gave it *to* her.

Acceptable:

> They fed the lion Ignatius.

Incorrect:

> They fed the lion him.

Acceptable:

> They fed him *to* the lion.

[By `Acceptable`, I refer to *grammar* only.]